# why can I use deduced return type without trailing return type in c++11?

Tags: c++, auto

I learned that auto deduced return type is a c++14 feature, just like below

```
template <typename Func, typename ...Args>
auto post(Func func, Args... args);
```

and I was told that if I want to use this in C++11, I must use trailing return type, like this

```
template <typename Func, typename ...Args>
auto post(Func func, Args... args) -> decltype(xxxxxx);
```

but actually I can compile the no-trailing-return-type one with `std=c++11` successfully in my PC, the compiler doesn't report error, it just report a warning like this:

```
warning: 'post' function uses 'auto' type specifier without trailing return type [enabled by default]
```

despite of this warning info, the program works fine as I designed. Why isn't it an error message?
I wonder why the compiler allow me to do this with `std=c++11` , since this is a c++14 feature. I notice there is a `[enabled by default]`  in the warning info. Does it mean the compiler forces itself to accept this syntax ? By the way, my compiler is gcc 4.8.5

I compile this with `std=c++11`(using gcc 4.8.5)

```
template <typename Func, typename ...Args>
auto post(Func func, Args... args);
```

I think it should report an error, but it just did report a warning and then allow me to do that:

```
warning: 'post' function uses 'auto' type specifier without trailing return type [enabled by default]
```

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you using the now antiquated GCC version 4.8.5? GCC is up to version 13.2 now. Eight years (how old version 4.8.5 is) is a *long* time for computer-related things, many things have happened since then.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Unfortunately I still use 4.8.5 because of my company. We use some special machines for developing, and the compiler version remains 4.8.5 for many reasons.  Later in next month we will update it to gcc 7.3.0

Comment: It might be a compiler extension to support some of the -then- future std features. The warning means the code my be not portable to other C++11 platforms.

Comment: Note that C++ standard does not make difference between "warnings" and "errors". In certain situations it requires implementations to issue diagnostic. You got diagnostic in C++11 mode so it is conforming. It may but is not required to fail compiling in any other situation but on case of #error preprocessor directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the compiler *has* the C++14 feature, to compile in C++14 mode. In C++11 mode, by default, it enables it, as a non-standard extension to the language. The option `-pedantic-errors` turns off those extensions, which will make it an error.

[See it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/s6hvEWsna)

Comment: thank you for your answer! It totally solved my problem.